# AZcopy (V10) How to copy data inside a folder in a storage account to another container in another storage account

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azcopy

Let us say, this path https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/container1/folder1 has some folders and files.

So I need to move these folders and files to the path https://yyyy.blob.core.windows.net/container2

Need to do this using Azcopy v10.

When Im trying this using azcopy v10, the files and folders are getting copied to below path
https://yyyy.blob.core.windows.net/container2/folder1/

folder1 has been created unexpectedly. I need to copy the data inside that folder1 folder to the container2.

AzCommand used was : 
.\azcopy cp "https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/0075696/0075696/[SASkey]" "https://yyyy.blob.core.windows.net/0075696/[SASKey]" --recursive=true

Comment: What's your previous AzCopy command line which resulted the unexpected creation of folder1? Could you please share it in your question?

Comment: .\azcopy cp "https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/0075696/0075696/[SASkey]" "https://yyyy.blob.core.windows.net/0075696/[SASKey]" --recursive=true

Comment: The command line you shared looks good to me. Maybe you need to create an issue to AzCopy V10 team on https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy

Answer (score 6):

Instead of specifying the folder as the source you need to specify the content of that folder.

```
https://myblobs.blob.core.windows.net/container1/?sp=... //copies the folder with content
https://myblobs.blob.core.windows.net/container1/*?sp=... //copies only the content
```

Answer (score 0):

Default option:
--as-subdir True by default. Places folder sources as subdirectories under the destination. (default true)

Set this to false - will put Folder1 content in Container2 without creating a subdirectory.

[Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-copy)